# Propagate default SQL Exception from DB2 stored procedure exit handler

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, jdbc, db2

I have a stored procedure which uses a global temporary table. I have defined an exit handler so that if an exception occurs anywhere in my procedure the global table is dropped.

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION drop table SESSION.TEMP_ODI_ID_TABLE;
```

This exit handler correctly catches the SQL Exception and drops the global table as required. However, the SQL Exception does not propagate and my Java code does not catch the SQL Exception as it would when not defining an exit handler explicitly. I would like to know how I can change the exit handler to drop the temporary table whilst still returning the SQL Exception which can be picked up by the catch statement in my JDBC code.

Thanks

Liam

Comment: Just like in Java, if you catch an exception and don't re-throw it, it is not propagated.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to embed a `SIGNAL` statement as part of the exit handler. That way you would also be able to react to the kind of SQL exception you are catching. Here is the link to the [SIGNAL statement](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0004232.html). ´SIGNAL` is used for raising errors within stored procedures, e.g. your application could signal a detected problem to the application without actually running into a SQL error.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved my problem by using RESIGNAL so that the SQL Exception is propagated after being caught by the exit handler.I am also going to implement some dynamic SQL so that the RESIGNAL returns the point at which my procedure caught the exception. The "quick" fix I applied for now is:

```
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
BEGIN
drop table SESSION.TEMP_ODI_ID_TABLE;
RESIGNAL;
END;
```